# Sending large amount of data sets over java web service

Tags: java, oracle, rest

I want to build a reports based application, that retrieve very large amount of data from oracle DB and display it to user, so my solution was to put a java based web service that returns a large amount of data. Is there a standard way to stream a response rather than trying to return a huge chunk of data at once?

Comment: That's going to be library-dependent. JAX-RS uses StreamingOutput, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider PAGING mechanism. Just display the required set of rows at once, then on request move to next set of rows.

From database end, you can do LIMIT and FETCH certain number of rows at a time.

If you are on 12c, the LIMIT TOP-n functionality is readily available.

Comment: I don't understand what you really mean, can you describe in more details. 
Thanx for your respond

Comment: What I mean is this http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php

Comment: oh I see, thnx Ill try that